# Unit test assertion that is true in several cases

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, mstest

I am trying to write a unit test where I check that a certain result is correct. However, there are two results that would be considered correct. Is there a way to do an OR with assertions?  I know that I could do result = x || result = y and assert that this is true.  But rather than seeing true != false, I would like to see result != x or y.

The framework I am using is mstest, but I would be open to hearing suggestions for nunit as well.

Comment: *Why* are there two answers that would be considered correct? Sounds like you've got an input that you're not controlling for, and you should really have two tests, one for each expected result (under the conditions where it's the *only* expected result).

Comment: @JoeWhite As an example, if you were testing a sorting algorithm and stability was not required in the specification, then multiple outputs might be considered to be correct for a particular input. The implementation will probably be deterministic, but you won't know how it's going to implemented. In my situation, the specification is not specific enough (which may be the real issue), so I have to account for multiple correct outputs.

Comment: In that case, what we do is assert the specific result our code gets. Unstable sorts are still deterministic (unless you're multithreaded). If you later change the algorithm and your test starts failing, you can see that the behavior is actually still correct, and update the test. Granted, that makes it more of a regression test than a unit test; but on the other hand, adding tests for outputs that are technically correct, but that you won't actually get with your implementation, is YAGNI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [Fluent Assertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/). This is a set of .NET extension methods that allow you to more naturally specify the expected outcome test. Fluent Assertions supports both MSTest and NUnit, so it will be not a big deal to switch later to nUnit. Then you could express your assertion using following snippet:

```
// Act phase: you get result somehow
var result = 42;

// Assert phase
result.Should().BeOneOf(new [] { 1, 2 } ); 
// in this case you'll be following error:
// Expected value to be one of {1, 41}, but found 42.
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice  *Constraint-Based Assert Model* in NUnit. It allows to define compound constraints. See details [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=constraintModel&r=2.4.8)

In your case assert might write:

```
Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(1).Or.EqualTo(5));
```

The failed test message would be (e.g.):
Expected: 1 or 5
  But was:  10

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
Assert.IsTrue( result == x || result == y );
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to just use `Assert.IsTrue`, but also pass a string message to print upon failure. That string can give the information about how the reality failed to meet the expectation:

```
Assert.IsTrue(result == x || result == y, "Result was not x or y");
```

You can easily include the actual value in your custom message also:

```
Assert.IsTrue(result == x || result == y, "Result was not x or y, instead it was {0}", result);
```

Alternatively, you could store your "correct" values in a Collection and then use [`CollectionAssert.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244248.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Assert method in case the actual result could match more than two expected values:

```
public void AssertMultipleValues<T>(object actual, params object[] expectedResults)
{
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(T));

    bool isExpectedResult = false;
    foreach (object expectedResult in expectedResults)
    {
        if(actual.Equals(expectedResult))
        {
            isExpectedResult = true;
        }
    }

    Assert.IsTrue(isExpectedResult, "The actual object '{0}' was not found in the expected results", actual);
}
```